# How to add Image to KML file using JAVA?

Tags: kml, java

I have implemented an Android app which adds user's current location with Lat , Long, Title (Location Title) , Remark & Image for the location (captured with Camera).

Now , What I want to achieve is add Image to KML file & to generate KML file without Image I'm using below code & it is working completely fine .

Here is code to generate KML file which includes lat , long , title & remark :

```
public void generateKMLFile()
{
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
    Document doc = builder.newDocument();
    Element root = doc.createElement("kml");
    root.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1");
    doc.appendChild(root);
    Element dnode = doc.createElement("Document");
    root.appendChild(dnode);
    Element rstyle = doc.createElement("Style");
    rstyle.setAttribute("id", "restaurantStyle");
    Element ristyle = doc.createElement("IconStyle");
    ristyle.setAttribute("id", "restaurantIcon");
    Element ricon = doc.createElement("Icon");
    Element riconhref = doc.createElement("href");
    riconhref.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon63.png"));
    rstyle.appendChild(ristyle);
    ricon.appendChild(riconhref);
    ristyle.appendChild(ricon);
    dnode.appendChild(rstyle);
    Element bstyle = doc.createElement("Style");
    bstyle.setAttribute("id", "barStyle");
    Element bistyle = doc.createElement("IconStyle");
    bistyle.setAttribute("id", "barIcon");
    Element bicon = doc.createElement("Icon");
    Element biconhref = doc.createElement("href");
    biconhref.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon27.png"));
    bstyle.appendChild(bistyle);
    bicon.appendChild(biconhref);
    bistyle.appendChild(bicon);
    dnode.appendChild(bstyle);

    Cursor c = mDatabaseManager.getAllLocations();
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        LocationBean lb = new LocationBean();
        lb.locationTitle = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.LOCATION_TITLE));
        lb.lat = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.LOCATION_LATITUDE));
        lb.log = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.LOCATION_LONGITUDE));
        lb.remark = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.LOCATION_REMARK));


        Element placemark = doc.createElement("Placemark");
        dnode.appendChild(placemark);
        Element name = doc.createElement("name");
        name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(lb.locationTitle));
        placemark.appendChild(name);
        Element descrip = doc.createElement("description");
        descrip.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(lb.remark));
        placemark.appendChild(descrip);
        Element styleUrl = doc.createElement("styleUrl");
        styleUrl.appendChild(doc.createTextNode( "#" +lb.locationTitle+ "Style"));
        placemark.appendChild(styleUrl);
        Element point = doc.createElement("Point");
        Element coordinates = doc.createElement("coordinates");
        coordinates.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(lb.log+ "," + lb.lat));
        point.appendChild(coordinates);
        placemark.appendChild(point);

    }

    Source src = new DOMSource(doc);
    Result dest = new StreamResult(new File("/sdcard/PlaceMarkers.kml")); // temporarily directly saved to sdcard
    aTransformer.transform(src, dest);
    System.out.println("Completed.....");


}
catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}
```

It generates KML file & I have imported it in Google Maps to check if it works & it is imported perfectly with location title & remark with marker on map.

How do I add an image to this KML file?

Note : location image is stored into SQLite database as BLOB data.